# Accessing a USB port in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, usb, libusb

In a Windows command-line window I can type:

```
c:\Windows\system32>echo Hello > \\.\LCLD9\
```

And output "Hello" to a USB [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) display (logic controls lt9000U). How would this be handled with C# in a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application?

Comment: Open the file named `@"\\.\LCLD9"` and write a byte array to the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no built in piping/cmd features in C#. You will need to pass args to cmd - see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands).

Comment: `ProcessInfo` most certainly support piping, but there's no program being executed here, just a text string and a file.